# how to make listview open full useable window on actionbar screen

Tags: xml, listview, android-actionbar, fullscreen, dock

hi guy's sorry for this silly question im new in andorid programming (1 month)
i have an actionbar and a list view on it 
 i need to  open list view in full  screen inside actionbar and use all usable space 
righ now i have a gap around listview

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#60c2ec"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

action bar prevent to show listview in full screen

Comment: i forgot to remove padding margine 
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"